# Questions on Sampling

Tags: sampling, sample-size, sample

Say I observe a random sample $s_i$ of a set $S$.
$\#S = N$
$\#s_i = n$
I observe that $k%$ of $n$ has property $P$.

Let $v$ represent the percentage of $S$ that has property $P$.

Given that I do not know $N$, what range should I assign to the value of $v$ given:
1. I know that $P$ is normally distributed on $S$. 
2. I do not know the distribution of $P$ on $S$.

Is the above solvable or do I need to know $N$?

Bonus: If I know $N$, what range do I assume to $v$ given:
1. I know that $P$ is normally distributed on $S$. 
2. I do not know the distribution of $P$ on $S$.

Standard deviation and the Chebyshev inequality are called thoughts that my brain outputs whenever I think of the above problem.

Comment: It's hard to reconcile "having property $P$," which sounds like a binary result--one has it or not; that's the only way I can make sense of converting it to a "percentage"--and the assumption of "normally distributed."  Could you clarify?

Comment: I agree with whuber.  The distribution of P has no impact on the answer to your question which just involves the number $\nu$ in the set S.

Comment: You could look at this in terms of the variance of the estimate of $\nu$ when randomly sampling without replacement from a finite population.